How to detect parity of the last page containing chapter material (either plain text or late floats)?
I have a (twosided) document, using (one of my classes which derives from) the book class, made up of chapters, each of which is stored in a dedicated file which is inserted into the main document using a dedicated command \myinput.
I'm asked to do the following: if the last page with the chapter content is an odd-numbered page, make the next page:

has an empty header,
is not taken into account in the chapter's page order in the table of contents.

For example, suppose a chapter begins on page 43 and ends on page 53 (so the next chapter begins on page 55). We then ask page 54 (which is “empty”: it contains nothing from this chapter) to have :

an empty header,
as page range in the table of contents “43-53” and not “43-54”.

Unfortunately, relying on a check at the end of the \myinput command isn't enough, since chapters may contain floats that are likely to float to pages after the one containing their very last material: in the example above, it's possible that the chapter's last words appear on page 52 and that page 53 contains only a float that LaTeX was unable to insert beforehand. (I rely on the placeins package to ensure that floats from one chapter cannot float to subsequent chapters.)
To sum up, I'd like to detect whether the last page containing material from a chapter (either ordinary text or late floats) is odd or not.
The following (not so useful) MCE is a draft that fails:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[above]{placeins}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\AddToHook{cmd/FloatBarrier/before}{%
  \message{^^J^^JBefore:}
  \ifoddpage
    \message{Odd page}
  \else
    \message{Even page}
  \fi
  \message{^^J^^J}
}

\AddToHook{cmd/FloatBarrier/after}{%
  \message{^^J^^JAfter:}
  \ifoddpage
    \message{Odd page}
  \else
    \message{Even page}
  \fi
  \message{^^J^^J}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1-10]
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.5\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Test 1}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-10]
\FloatBarrier
\chapter{Second}
\lipsum[1-10]
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.5\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Test 2}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-5]
\FloatBarrier
\chapter{Third}
\lipsum[1-10]
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.5\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Test 2}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}

Any idea?

check the definition of \cleardoublepage. It knows when to insert a blank page. (I don't know why you need a floatbarrier before a chapter, they issue a \cleardoublepage).

@UlrikeFischer The floatbarrier is here to ensure that floats from one chapter cannot float to subsequent chapters but maybe it is useless: is \chapter already a barrier for floats?

\clearpage flushes out floats, unless you have redefined it.

The code doesn't display page ranges. How do you do them?

@egreg I could add the corresponding code but that's a bit long and tricky. Essentially I store in the .aux file the first page of each chapter in a comma separated list then put in another comma separated list the range from the 1st page of the previous chapter until the page which precedes the 1st page of the current chapter.

@egreg In my answer below, I've simplified the process for obtaining page ranges.

Thanks to Ulrike's comment, I managed to get what I was asked to provide.
Below is a CE of it where:

I failed to patch the TOC so create my on “new list of” (chapters),
ltproperties might probably have been helpful,
comments are lacking (sorry).

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{chap1.tex}
\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1-10]
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.5\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Test 1}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{chap2.tex}
\chapter{Second}
\lipsum[1-10]
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.5\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Test 2}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{chap3.tex}
\chapter{Third}
\lipsum[1-10]
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.5\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Test 2}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newlistof{chapters}{chp}{Contents}
\setlength{\cftbeforechaptersskip}{\cftbeforechapskip}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\int_new:N \g__my_chapter_number_int
\tl_new:N \l__my_page_range_chapter_tl
\tl_new:N \g__my_title_chapter_tl
\clist_new:N \g__my_pages_ranges_chapters_clist
\clist_new:N \g__my_pages_ranges_chapters_temp_clist

\xapptocmd{\@chapter}{
  \tl_gset:Nn \g__my_title_chapter_tl {#1}
  \addtocontents{chp}{\protect\cftpagenumbersoff{chapters}}
  \addcontentsline{chp}{chapters}{\bfseries%
    \protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1
    \hfill
    \clist_item:Nn \g__my_pages_ranges_chapters_clist {\g__my_chapter_number_int}
  }
}{}{\aaa}

\cftsetrmarg{0cm}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myinput}{m}{
  \__my_input:n {#1}
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__my_input:n {
  \int_incr:N \g__my_chapter_number_int
  \tl_clear:N \l__my_page_range_chapter_tl
  \clearpage
  \ifodd
    \c@page
    \tl_set:Ne \l__my_page_range_chapter_tl  {\thepage}
  \else
    \tl_set:Ne \l__my_page_range_chapter_tl  {\int_eval:n { \thepage+1 }}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
  \fi
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__my_page_range_chapter_tl {–}
  \input{#1}
  \clearpage
  \tl_put_right:Ne \l__my_page_range_chapter_tl {\inteval{\thepage-1}}
  \clist_gput_right:Ne \g__my_pages_ranges_chapters_temp_clist {\l__my_page_range_chapter_tl}
}
\AddToHook{enddocument/afterlastpage}{
  \iow_now:ce { @auxout } {
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \clist_gset:Nn \token_to_str:N \g__my_pages_ranges_chapters_clist {
      \clist_use:Nn \g__my_pages_ranges_chapters_temp_clist {,}
    }
    \ExplSyntaxOff
  }
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\listofchapters
\myinput{chap1}
\myinput{chap2}
\myinput{chap3}
\end{document}

